# Should the OpenAPI definition be public?

Tags: security, openapi

We have an OpenAPI definition (json, using swagger), and I wonder what's a good practice to meet security concerns:

I could either make the openapi.json file public (and restrict access to the services themselves by using security requirements inside the openapi definition), or I could already protect the openapi.json resource, and thus hide the description of which services are available.

Of course, making less information available is more secure, but it will make interfaces with tools that depend on OpenAPI more complicated. What's your experience? What's a good practice? Will a public OpenAPI definition be flagged in security audits?

Comment: Is your API documentation public or private? An OpenAPI definition file is also documentation, it's just primarily intended for use with tools (codegen, automated testing tools, Swagger UI, etc.)

Comment: @Helen Good point. Technically, our documentation is private, i.e. we only make it available to people who purchase a license. And I guess that's the core question: Do we want to keep the documentation private.

Another thought: Part of the OpenAPI description is whether services are protected (by authentication). As a consequence, people will use the OpenAPI description to understand which authentication method they need to use. It feels awkward that they need to authenticate *before* they are told to do so.

Comment: In my experience, an OpenAPI definition should be available to anyone who is expecting to integrate with it. If that's just licensed customers, then it'd be available to them. If it's the general public, likewise. (Also, 'security by obscurity' isn't a great strategy by itself.)